# How to access the internal function?

Tags: javascript, closures, phaser-framework, phaserjs

```
var $jscomp = $jscomp || {};
$jscomp.scope = {};
$jscomp.ASSUME_ES5 = !1;
$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_MAP = !1;
$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_SET = !1;
$jscomp.SIMPLE_FROUND_POLYFILL = !1;
$jscomp.objectCreate =
  $jscomp.ASSUME_ES5 || "function" == typeof Object.create
    ? Object.create
    : function (e) {
        var m = function () {};
        m.prototype = e;
        return new m();
      };
$jscomp.underscoreProtoCanBeSet = function () {
  var e = { a: !0 },
    m = {};
  try {
    return (m.__proto__ = e), m.a;
  } catch (w) {}
  return !1;
};
$jscomp.setPrototypeOf =
  "function" == typeof Object.setPrototypeOf
    ? Object.setPrototypeOf
    : $jscomp.underscoreProtoCanBeSet()
    ? function (e, m) {
        e.__proto__ = m;
        if (e.__proto__ !== m) throw new TypeError(e + " is not extensible");
        return e;
      }
    : null;
$jscomp.inherits = function (e, m) {
  e.prototype = $jscomp.objectCreate(m.prototype);
  e.prototype.constructor = e;
  if ($jscomp.setPrototypeOf) {
    var w = $jscomp.setPrototypeOf;
    w(e, m);
  } else
    for (w in m)
      if ("prototype" != w)
        if (Object.defineProperties) {
          var B = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(m, w);
          B && Object.defineProperty(e, w, B);
        } else e[w] = m[w];
  e.superClass_ = m.prototype;
};

var Game = function () {
  return Phaser.Scene.call(this, "game") || this;
};
$jscomp.inherits(Game, Phaser.Scene);
Game.prototype.create = function () {
  this.someFunctionName = fn;
  function fn(a) {
    dosomething...
  }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    transparent: !0,
    width: 720,
    height: 1080,
    scale: {
      mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
      parent: "game_content",
      autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    },
    scene: [Boot, Load, Menu, Level, Game],
  },
game = new Phaser.Game(config);

game.create();
console.log(game.someFunctionName());
```

So how to access the function fn? So how to access the function fn?

Can't access the function fn! Got this error "caught TypeError: game.create is not a function". I just want to use the fn function outsider.

Can't access the function fn! Got this error "caught TypeError: game.create is not a function". I just want to use the fn function outsider.

Comment: How and Why do you want to want to access this function? is the function ***static*** or not?  basically without changing the code you can't call the function, that's why more context, on how you want to use it, is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your usecase you could simply attach the function to the current instance:

```
...
var Game = function () {
    return Phaser.Scene.call(this, "game") || this;
};

$jscomp.inherits(Game, Phaser.Scene);

Game.prototype.create = function () {
 
    function fn(a){
        ...
    }

    this.someFunctionName = fn; // <-- an easy solution, works in some cases
}
```

And than you can access the function through the `someFunctionName` method. *(but you will need to call the  `create` function on the instance, so that the function is bound to the instance)*

> I removed the ***alternative Version***, since after thinking about it it is a very bad way to solve this problem

**UPDATE:**
***Disclaimer:** This should work, but I don't know why you would ever want to do this.*

```
...
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

// the game is not created right await you need to wait, abit.
setTimeout( ( ) => {
    console.info(game.scene.keys['game'].someFunctionName())
}, 0);
...
```

***Info:** the key `game` is due to the parameter passed, to this line of code `return Phaser.Scene.call(this, "game") || this;`. If this value would change you would have to adapt it, in both places.*

> personally I would use ES6 inheritance to create Custom Scene this makes everything more readable. [Checkout this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/change%20scene%20from%20create%20es6.js)

Comment: Got "undefined" console message by using Game.prototype.someFunctionName. @winner_joiner

Comment: You would have to call the `someFunctionName` on an instance, so with other Words `var test = Game(); test.someFunctionName();`, but there are other ways I updated an alternative.

Comment: Got this console message "Game.someFunctionName is not a function"@winner_joiner

Comment: Sorry the alternative is a possible solution, but it is not really good. Since it still only will work if the `create` function is called atleast once. Why don't you just uset the first version. You just need to call `create` on the instance before calling the `someFunctionName`. `var test = Game(); ...; test.create(); ....; test.someFunctionName();`

Comment: The first version got the error message "test.create is not a function".

Comment: I don't know `jscomp.inherits` does, your code ist not really clear too me. if `jscomp`is extending a class the creating of test should look like this `var test = new Game()`, If using the new keyword doesn't solve your problem it might be better to share more code explaining, what you want to achieve. ***btw.:** You can update your question, you don't need to post code in an answer.*

Comment: I update the code. Got an error too.

Comment: @uronpen I updated my answer with a working solution.

Comment: @uronpen no problem, if it solved your question, please consider accepting my answer with the green checkmark. :)